# How to read lines from a mmapped file?

Tags: python, file, text, mmap

Is seems that the mmap interface only supports readline(). 
If I try to iterate over the object I get character instead of complete lines.

What would be the "pythonic" method of reading a mmap'ed file line by line?

```
import sys
import mmap
import os


if (len(sys.argv) > 1):
  STAT_FILE=sys.argv[1]
  print STAT_FILE
else:
  print "Need to know <statistics file name path>"
  sys.exit(1)


with open(STAT_FILE, "r") as f:
  map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
  for line in map:
    print line # RETURNS single characters instead of whole line
```

Comment: Out of interest, what's the motivation for using a memory-mapped file for this, as opposed to a normal file?

Comment: @aix: I could possibly have GB's of raw data, and I would like to access them in the most efficient method possible. But the real reason is: It's cooler :)

Comment: I don't know whether it's cooler, but you shouldn't simply assume that it's faster (if you really care, you ought to profile).

Comment: I added some timings to my post below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The most concise way to iterate over the lines of an `mmap` is

```
with open(STAT_FILE, "r+b") as f:
    map_file = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    for line in iter(map_file.readline, b""):
        # whatever
```

Note that in Python 3 the sentinel parameter of `iter()` must be of type `bytes`, while in Python 2 it needs to be a `str` (i.e. `""` instead of `b""`).

Comment: I didn't know `iter` took this `callable`/`sentinel` argument pair. +1 and removed my answer in favor of this one.

Comment: And please change the open mode to `r+b` instead of `r` (as mentioned in my post below).

Comment: For Windows, use `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ`, see: [Loading file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13500434/55075).

Comment: @SvenMarnach could you please explain why on readline you use the b"" second parameter? Thanks

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis The two-argument version of `iter()` basically means: call the function in the first argument repeatedly and yield the successive return values, but stop once the sentinel in the second argument is returned. So we basically call `map_file.readline()` until it doesn't return any more data. For regular files you could simply write `for line in file`, but `mmap` does not support line iteration directly, so we need to use `iter()`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach How can I get the count of lines in a big file to avoid memory issues using mmap ?

Comment: @Kar Your question does not have enough context for me to answer it, and it also seems unrelated, so I suggest you ask a new question. For what it's worth, there are numerous questions here on how to count the number of items in an iterator, e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/election. As long as you don't store the whole file in memory at once, there shouldn't be any memory issues, regardless of whether you use `mmap()` or `open()`.

Answer (score 15):

I modified your example like this:

```
with open(STAT_FILE, "r+b") as f:
        m=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
        while True:
                line=m.readline()
                if line == '': break
                print line.rstrip()
```

**Suggestions:**

- Do not call a variable `map`, this is a built-in function.
- Open the file in **`r+b` mode**, as in the Python example on the `mmap` help page. It states: *In either case you must provide a file descriptor for a file opened for update*. See http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html#mmap.mmap.
- It's better to not use `UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` global variable names, as mentioned in *Global Variable Names* at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#global-variable-names. In other programming languages (like C), constants are often written all uppercase.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** I did some timing tests on Linux because the comment made me curious. Here is a comparison of timings made on 5 sequential runs on a 137MB text file.

Normal file access:

```
real    2.410 2.414 2.428 2.478 2.490
sys     0.052 0.052 0.064 0.080 0.152
user    2.232 2.276 2.292 2.304 2.320
```

`mmap` file access:

```
real    1.885 1.899 1.925 1.940 1.954
sys     0.088 0.108 0.108 0.116 0.120
user    1.696 1.732 1.736 1.744 1.752
```

Those timings do not include the `print` statement (I excluded it). Following these numbers I'd say memory mapped file access is quite a bit faster.

**Edit 2:** Using `python -m cProfile test.py` I got the following results:

```
5432833    2.273    0.000    2.273    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'file' objects}
5432833    1.451    0.000    1.451    0.000 {method 'readline' of 'mmap.mmap' objects}
```

If I'm not mistaken then `mmap` is quite a bit faster.

Additionally, it seems `not len(line)` performs worse than `line == ''`, at least that's how I interpret the profiler output.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'mmap.mmap' object has no attribute 'readlines'`

Comment: hochl: Thank you. The benchmarks are great. Could you attach a script to reproduce the test and confirm the analysis?

Comment: I simply commented out the print in your program and then did `time test.py` like 10 times, then took the 5 middle values. It would be interesting to check the results of `python -m cProfile test.py`.

Answer (score 1):

The following is reasonably concise:

```
with open(STAT_FILE, "r") as f:
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
    while True:
        line = m.readline()  
        if line == "": break
        print line
    m.close()
```

Note that `line` retains the newline, so you might like to remove it. It is also the reason why `if line == ""` does the right thing (an empty line is returned as `"\n"`).

The reason the original iteration works the way it does is that `mmap` tries to look like both a file and a string. It looks like a string for the purposes of iteration.

I have no idea why it can't (or chooses not to) provide `readlines()/xreadlines()`.

Comment: The `readlines()` method of file objects returns a list of all lines of the file.  doing this on an mmapped file would completely defeat the purpose of the mmap.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: It could be a generator. In any case, to be totally honest I fail to see the need for memory-mapped files in this entire question.

Comment: You are completely right.  So maybe the reason for the non-existence of such a generator is that it would be pointless. :)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7 32bit on Windows is *more than twice as fast* on an mmapped file:

On a 27MB, 509k line text file (my 'parse' function is not interesting it mostly just readline()'s very rapidly):

```
with open(someFile,"r") as f:
    if usemmap:
        m=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    else:
        m=f
        e.parse(m)
```

With MMAP:

```
read in 0.308000087738
```

Without MMAP:

```
read in 0.680999994278
```

Answer (score -1):

Even better in case you get error with `mmap()`:

```
with open('/content/drive/MyDrive......', "r+b") as f:
    # map_file = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ) as mmap not recogn. import something
    for line in iter(f.readline, b""):
      print(line)
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76319805/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).