# loading file in memory using Python

Tags: python, mmap

I try to load a file in memory with this:

```
import mmap

with open(path+fileinput+'example.txt', 'rb') as f:
       fileinput = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
```

When I run the code the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROT_READ'
```

Comment: How are you testing how many lines it gives?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `PROT_READ` and `PROT_WRITE` are Unix-specific. You're likely looking for:

```
mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
```

The [`mmap` page](http://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) actually has different entries for Unix/Windows version.

Answer (score 2):

I recently got the same error message with my test program mmap.py.  Renaming my test program to something else (mmap_test.py) fixed the name collision that caused numpy's memmap.py to get when it executed 'import mmap'.